# Correct use of code block formatting?

Tags: support, code-formatting

Is the following correct use of a code block (the curly braces icon) in a Stack Overflow question?

```
def __init__(self,rect_len,rect_wid,stylus_in):
        self.len = rect_len
        self.wid = rect_wid
        self.stylus = stylus_in
```

When should I use a block quote (see following)?

> Some block quote text

Comment: What curly braces (`{}`)?

Comment: @Larnu the "curly braces" is the icon on the old (current) Stack Editor's toolbar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A code block is for when you have code; hence why it's called a code block. A quote block is for when you are quoting something; that might be an article, documentation, a quote/comment, book, or even an error. If that quote constrains code then the code inside the quote block should also be in a code block.

A very rudimentary example would be for a code block:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

As for a quote, you might use it in the following context:

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#a-running-a-simple-example) gives the following example for the `COALESCE` function:

> ### A. Running a simple example
>
> The following example shows how `COALESCE` selects the data from the first column that has a nonnull value. This example uses the AdventureWorks2019 database.
>
> ```sql
> SELECT Name, Class, Color, ProductNumber,  
> COALESCE(Class, Color, ProductNumber) AS FirstNotNull  
> FROM Production.Product;
> ```

Some things that aren't code may also, however, be better in a code block. For example if you posting part of a stack trace from an application that is erroring, these often are better put in a code block, due to the fact that they formatted better™, as they lend themselves to fixed-width fonts.